# xcode 7 conflicted shortcut cannot be removed

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I added a shortcut key to "Clear Constraints" in the xcode preferences, and xcode installed the shortcut twice under different xcode names. (See the image.)

The problem is that there is no little "-" (minus) sign (see the red arrow in the image) to remove my duplicate shortcut attempt, because any key I press is interpreted as a shortcut combination.

The problem shortcut(s) are shown below the red arrow. The red arrow one is fine, I just wanted to show the little "-" minus sign there.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem (without reinstalling xcode and all my custom keybindings :-)). Thanks

[Image showing duplicate shortcuts below red arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmKbc.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quit Xcode. Restart the computer just to be on the safe side: we want to force Xcode to write its preferences out to disk.

Go to ~Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings. Open the key bindings file with a good text editor.

You are now editing XML; I presume you know what you're doing. You will see two `<dict>` entries whose `<action>` starts with `clearConstraints`. Delete those entries. Save.

Comment: And you might as well file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: What a beautiful answer, Matt -- it was dead on target and solved the problem perfectly. As for filing a bug report with Apple, I have no idea how to do that with such a big company. I wonder if you could point me towards any doc that explained the fields in the XML file? That way I might be able to intelligently edit the file to add a custom keybinding to one of those two fields, without triggering the duplicate problem... Thank you again for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Bug reports go to http://bugreport.apple.com - as for the XML file, I don't think you should be editing it by hand in general. My job was to get you out of the mess that Apple's bug created; any further playing with the XML is more likely to get you into more of a mess! :) I suspect that, with this bug, you _can't_ give this action a custom keyboard shortcut; that, indeed, _is_ the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will file a report at apple. I considered trying to delete only one of the two instances (because they were different in the XML), to see if I could keep one binding. But then I thought.... why push it the first time, why not just do what the guy says, I can always reproduce the bug later if I like. But I haven't felt the need to go back in there. TTYL

Comment: Ok, I am now an official bug reporter to Apple. This bug is # 24921768. Thanks Matt!

Comment: It's an annoying web page, for sure, but we all just suck it up and report those bugs. Well done!

Comment: Yeah, I had to suck it up when I got to the very end of entering all those fields, and lightly brushed my oh-so-delicate Mac super mouse a little too much sideways by accident, and Poof! the mouse went back to the previous browser page and lost my entire 5 or 10 minutes of typing and image gathering, etc.  Lesson learned! Be VERY careful reaching for the mouse when filling out those long forms! Thanks again -- my xcode life is better for all of your help.